# jQuery fill in HTML codes in a DIV by API call

Tags: jquery

I have a hyperlink that shows a DIV by calling the following function:

```
<div id="btn" onclick="showUI()">I'm a button</div>
<div id="panel" style="display: none">I'm hidden initially.</div>
<script>
function showUI(element) {
    $('#panel').html('Loading...');
    $('#panel').show();
    var content = api_call();
    $('#panel').html(content);
    return false;
}
function api_call() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/myAPI/',
        async: false,
        data: {q: 'fetch_sth_great', id: 1, token: '123456'},
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            return data;
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr, status) {
        if (status == "error") {
            return "Sorry but there was an error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

From the Development Console of Google Chrome, the AJAX call responses with a well-structured XML, which contains contents that I want to show in the DIV `$('#panel')`, and status `200 OK`. However, the function `api_call()` returns `undefined`.

However, when I use the following codes for another API call, the DIV is successfully filled with the data.

```
$('#panel').load('ajax/myAPI/', {q: 'fetch_sth_great', id: id, token: '123456'}, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#panel").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
```

What I am trying the achieve is, by an onclick function, fetch the contents from my API ( which returns valid XML / HTML contents ), and show it in a specific DIV. But before showing the responded contents, I have to add more contents before & after it. Therefore, I cannot use `$.load()` method.

What did I miss in the above codes ?

Using jQuery 1.9.1 with jQuery Migrate 1.1.0

*Note:* No JavaScript or server-side error in the whole process.

**UPDATE:** Sample XML contents returned by XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<response>
  <ui><![CDATA[some html here]]></ui>
</response>
```

and I want to grab the content of xpath: `/response/ui`

Comment: The assumption that return data from the success function, returns a value from the api_call function is incorrect. The return data in the success function is going nowhere.  I would populate the $('#panel') from inside the success function

Comment: Is there any method that I can pass back the contents from the `api_call()`? The function aims to centralize all calls, so that the function may get called from many other functions.

Comment: Give api_call a callback

Comment: how to add a callback in this case? By the way, I just tried to populate the `$('#panel')` in `.ajax().success`, and now the content is `[object Document]`. I thought it can load the contents into the DIV, but it becomes an object. Anything I missed again?

Comment: So just out of interest, when you say that the response is well-structure XML, what is it exactly you want to show on the page. Is it all of that XML, or is just an extract of one of the XML nodes. If you could, add the XML to your question

Comment: I will extract one of the node contents out of the XML, but the XML parsing codes are omitted for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this

```
<div id="btn" onclick="showUI()">I'm a button</div>
<div id="panel" style="display: none">I'm hidden initially.</div>
<script>
function showUI(element) {
    $('#panel').html('Loading...');
    $('#panel').show();
    api_call(function(content){
            //Note: Content would be the XML returned from the AJAX call
            // So traversing to find the data required would need to be done here
            // Something like:
            var exValue = $(content).find('node').text();
            $('#panel').html(exValue);
        });

    return false;
}
function api_call(successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/myAPI/',
        async: false,
        data: {q: 'fetch_sth_great', id: 1, token: '123456'},
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            successCallBack(data);
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr, status) {
        if (status == "error") {
            return "Sorry but there was an error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The 1st method works like charm, but for 2nd method, the AJAX call got cancelled. Marked as `(canceled)` in Developer Console status.

Comment: Yeah I had my doubts, I'll remove it from the answer as not really helpful as it doesn't work.